# C# How to restrict interface properties

Tags: c#, properties, interface

I have one interface which is inherited by a few classes, some of the properties however are being set only by the constructor of the classes. I will never change the values of those properties outside of the constructor so I want to restrict the properties by having them with a private setter, but the interface doesn't allow me to use properties with any type of modifiers how can i work around this ?

Comment: perhaps remove the setters from the interface?

Comment: You can't do that other than to document your intent and "hope" that whoever implements the interface follows your guideline.

Comment: Sow a [mcve] to better show what you have and what you want

Comment: Yes, remove the setter from the interface, and back off the getter with a `private readonly` field (which can, by definition, only be manipulated in the constructor). This is a stronger contract than that offered by a `private set`, which can be manipulated *after* construction. This would appear to completely solve the constraints of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces are there to describe things that any implementing type must be able to do.  It's not capable of defining thinks that it *can't* do.

The interface can define that there must be a given property getter of an appropriate name and type, but it can't specify that there must *not* be a public setter for that property.

You're certainly welcome to provide documentation with this interface suggesting that implementors have a private setter, or even that they never allow the value to change outside of a constructor, but there's no way for an interface to specify such a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce immutability for these properties on a compiler and language level.

In other words, there is no way for you to write your interface such that immutability for these properties is the only thing that is allowed, nor that they don't have a public setter *in the class*.

The language simply does not have any syntax which allows you to express this requirement.

You *can* declare the properties in your interface without setters but you cannot require the actual properties in the implementation to

1. Have no setters
2. Never change their value

Please note that if you only expose the implementation classes through the interface then only the access methods you declare in the interface will be available. In other words, if your interface only declares a getter, you cannot set the value through the interface.

Your best option is simply to document this part of the interface contract and hope that whoever implements this interface follows your intent and guideline.

Answer (score -1):

In your interface specify only a getter:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    int SomeProperty { get; }
}
```

Your implementations are free to set it privately:

```
class Foo : ISomeInterface
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
         SomeProperty = 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't force the property getter to be private, it just *allows* it to be private.

Comment: @Servy can you clarify what would change if could force the property's getter to be private ?

Comment: @PreqlSusSpermaOhranitel It would mean that you couldn't create an implementation of the interface that allowed the value to be mutated outside of the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using a readonly struct instead of a class. Of course there are a lot of drawbacks, such as not being able to use an interface (at least not without boxing) and having to use copy semantics (which are slower if the struct is large).

By using a readonly struct you can require that the properties are immutable.

Comment: That was never the question. The question is how you can declare an interface that *requires* the implementing type to do it immutable. There are plenty of ways to make the implementing type immutable, but that was not the question.